# Deploy both front and backend using helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I have a monorepo nodejs/react app that I want to deploy to GKE using Helm charts. I added two Dockerfiles one for the frontend and the other for the back.

I'm using Helm Charts to deploy my microservices to the Kubernetes cluster but this time I don't know how to configure it so that I can deploy both back and front simultaneously to GKE.

Should I configure a values.yaml file for each service and keep the other templates as they are (ingress, service, deployment, hpa) or should I work on each service independently?

Comment: I'd probably put both parts into the same Helm chart, probably with different `templates/*.yaml` files for the front- and back-end parts.  If you had a good argument that the two parts are separate (maybe different development teams work on them and you have a good public API contract) it's fine to deploy them separately though.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as an answer for better visibility since it's a good solution:

[David suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70436517/deploy-both-front-and-backend-using-helm-charts#comment124510627_70436517) that you can

> probably put both parts into the same Helm chart, probably with different `templates/*.yaml` files for the front-and back-end parts.
>
> If you had a good argument that the two parts are separate (maybe different development teams work on them and you have a good public API contract) it's fine to deploy them separately